# Installing Scala 2.9.1/Lift 2.4-M4 using sbt 0.11.0

Tags: macos, scala, jetty, lift, sbt

I am learning to do web development in Scala. currently trying to install the newest version of Scala/lift with sbt 0.11 in MAC OSX. I so far have already done the following:
1. Installed Scala 2.9.1 final
2. Downloaded latest sbt 0.11 from https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Setup
3. Setup path environment for sbt

What I am trying to do now is getting the latest lift framework (2.4-M4)from http://liftweb.net/download so that I can try running lift_basic project on localhost:8080 using jetty. I have several questions about that;

- Since on the sbt 0.11 I will have to do this:

  `resolvers += "Web plugin repo" at "http://siasia.github.com/maven2"
  addSbtPlugin("com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.1.2")`

  instead of doing `libraryDependencies += ...` where should I put my object resolvers (checkout the following code below) that would enable me to install both the jetty and web plugin? so, under lift_basic folder should they go within Project/build/LiftProject.Scala or just delete LiftProject.scala and create Build.scala under Project/Build.scala?

  `object Resolvers {
        val webPluginRepo = "Web plugin repo" at "http://siasia.github.com/maven2"
        val jettyRepo = "Jetty Repo" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty"
      }`

  ```
  object Dependencies {
        // web plugin
        val webPluginDeps = Seq(
          "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.26" % "jetty", // The last part is "jetty" not "test".
          "javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.5" % "provided->default"
        )
  ```
- What should I do with the sbt.jar existing inside the lift_basic folder? It looks like that it has the old version of sbt there (probably 7.4.0 or so)..
- Besides changing the sbt version to 0.11.0 on the Build.properties, what other changes do I need to make to accomodate this new install? Do I have to change the `var BuildScalaVersion` and `var buildVersion` on the Build.scala on the full configuration like the example https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration-Example here? If yes, what would be the build version?

I am a total newbie to Scala, and there hasnt been a lot of documentations out there for installing new scala/lift version. will appreciate any pointers/references/answers that would enable me to install new version of scala/lift. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to look at my project template. Maybe It will be helpful. https://github.com/viktortnk/lift-quickstart

Comment: hey thanks, i'll try that. were you able to see run the jetty and see the app running on port 8080 in localhost?

Comment: Nice one, thanks @darwin! First the Origin of Species and now this.